# Ruby Prawn Add METADATA to a template

Tags: ruby, metadata, prawn

I can not seem to set the METADATA to the pdf generated based on a template. Is this NOT allowed or did I do something wrong.

Here is the code

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:template => "sample.pdf",
                          :info => {
                            :Title        => "Sample METADATA",
                            :Author       => "Me",
                            :Subject      => "Not Working",
                            :CreationDate => Time.now,
                          })
```

Thanks you .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this happens because of this issue:
https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/417

I think it has been solved and merged to master 22 days ago.